# How can I get a ply format file from arcore point cloud?

Tags: java, android, arcore

First of all, I'm sorry for my poor English.
I have a Galaxy Note 10+. And it includes a ToF sensor.
I am looking for a way to change point cloud into a ply format file using Google arcore in my project. But I haven't found the right answer yet.
If possible, I would like to change it to a binary type of ply. If it's hard, other ways are fine. Please help me.

+Additional Description

```
PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
pointCloudVertexBuffer.set(pointCloud.getPoints());
```

I would like to use the same method as the above code provided by arcore.
I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there is a library suitable for use.
If possible, please let me know java library, not c/c++.

Comment: Uhm, I found this in 2 secs of Googling: ArPointCloud_getData(const ArSession *session, const ArPointCloud *point_cloud, const float **out_point_cloud_data) should give you all you need. Possibly you'd have to link in some ply-writing code or library, check out miniply / happly / rply / on git, check https://github.com/mhalber/ply_io_benchmark